# How to access updated document during mongoose post update middleware?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, middleware

I'm wondering if there is any reliable/reusable way to access the updated document during a mongoose post update middleware hook. All I seem to have access to is:

```
schema.post('update', function (result) {
  console.log(this) // Mongoose Query, no relevant doc info
  console.log(result) // Mongoose CommandResult, no relevant doc info
})
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Instead of `schema.post('update', ...)` try `schema.post('findOneAndUpdate', function(result) { console.log(result); });` instead to get access to the modified doc.

Answer (score 2):

this also works on `update/updateOne/updateMany`

```
schema.post('update', function (documents) {
  this.model.find(this._conditions).then(documents => {
    console.log(documents.length)
  }
})
```

Comment: actually it doesn't work in all cases. e.g: if you modify a field you are querying the post find query will not return the modified documents because they will not match the query anymore.

Answer (score 1):

In the Query object you receive in the post hook, you have access to the parameters sent to the query. You can get it like this

```js
_conditions: { id: 'cjauvboxb0000xamdkuyb1fta' }

const id = this._conditions.id
```

Comment: This only works if you pass in the id during your function as a parameter. Is there a way to get the id of the document if you are not querying by id?

Answer (score -2):

`Schema.post('update')` is only used in error handling (custom error messages)

```
// The same E11000 error can occur when you call `update()`
// This function **must** take 3 parameters. If you use the
// `passRawResult` function, this function **must** take 4
// parameters
Schema.post('update', function(error, res, next) {
  if (error.name === 'MongoError' && error.code === 11000) {
    next(new Error('There was a duplicate key error'));
  } else {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

If you wanted to add an updatedAt timestamp to every update() call for example, you would use the following pre hook.

```
Schema.pre('update', function() {
  this.update({},{ $set: { updatedAt: new Date() } });
});
```

[Read official docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but it's probably because you misunderstood the docs. An error handler middleware must take 3 or 4 parameters, if not, it will be treated as a normal middleware. It has nothing to do with it been a post update middleware.